# Home page isn't rendering in the app although I think my code is correct. the one who can show the mistake will be so helpful to me

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, rendering, router

I am trying to render the HomePage using react Router and it didn't work. I've stuck in this problem for two days. Your support will be greatly appreciated. I tried so many times to resolve this problem without being able to solve it. I used chatgpt and other tools to see what's wrong with my code but all went in vain and without satisfying answer```
type here

```
import React from "react";

import "../styles/Home.css";

function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div className="home">
      <h1>hello world from here</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePage;


import "./App.css";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={HomePage} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Which version of `react-router-dom` are you using?

Comment: react-router-dom version 6.15.0

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple default exports. You are exporting as default both App and Homepage component.
Try to default export only App, considering also that the `Home` component is used directly on the same file.